ASK error probability
I'm resolving this exercise and calculated the capacity using the formula $C=Blog 2(1+SNR)$. I found the probability of error to be equal to $Q(\sqrt{\frac{A^2T}{4N_0}})$ I'm supposed to convert this probability error to $Q(\sqrt{2RSB})$; what I know is the energy per bit here is $E_b=\frac{A^2T}{4}$ with the PSD of noise is $N_0$ then the $RSB=\frac{E_b}{N_0}\frac{Datarate}{Bandwidth}$ and it doesn't give the same final result. Did I make an error?
Problem
Binary data is to be transmitted over a telephone line with a bandwidth of 3 kHz and a signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) of 6 dB at its output.

Determine the maximum signaling rate (channel capacity).
If ASK modulation is used for transmission:Show that the bit error probability can be expressed as $Q(\sqrt{2RSB})$


We begin by noting that the Shannon–Hartley theorem gives the channel capacity as:
$$C = B\log_{2}(1 + \text{SNR})$$
In this problem, we have a telephone line of bandwidth $B=3000\,\text{Hz}$ and $\text{SNR} = 6\,\text{dB}$, i.e. $\text{SNR}=10^{6/10}\approx4$. Substituting:
$$
\begin{aligned}
C &= 3000 \log_{2}(1 + 4) \\
&= 3000 \log_{2}(5) \\
&\approx 3000 \times 2.32 \\
&\approx 6960\,\text{bits per second}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, the maximum signaling rate (channel capacity) is roughly $7\,\text{kbits/s}$.
For the bit error probability in on-off keying or amplitude shift keying (ASK), we can use the standard coherent detection result. When transmitting a single bit of duration $T$ with amplitude $A$ for bit "1" and amplitude 0 for bit "0," the energy per bit becomes:
$$E_b = \frac{A^2T}{4}$$
where the factor $1/4$ comes from the rectangular pulse shape $\sqrt{A^2}$ times the duty cycle for on–off signaling. If we denote by $N_0$ the single-sided power spectral density of white Gaussian noise, the bit-error probability for coherent ASK with a matched filter is:
$$P_b = Q\!\left(\sqrt{\frac{2E_b}{N_0}}\right)$$
We may also see forms like $Q\!\left(\sqrt{\frac{A^2T}{2N_0}}\right)$, which expresses the same relationship since $E_b = \frac{A^2T}{4}$ implies $2E_b = \frac{A^2T}{2}$.
When expressing the probability of error in terms of:
$$Q\!\left(\sqrt{2RSB}\right)$$
where:
$$RSB = \frac{E_b}{N_0} \frac{R}{B}$$
Here $R$ is the bit rate (bits/s), and $B$ is the (two-sided) bandwidth. Since $T=1/R$ for each bit:
$$\frac{A^2T}{4N_0} = \frac{E_b}{N_0} = \frac{E_b}{N_0}\frac{R}{B} \times \frac{B}{R} = (RSB)\frac{B}{R}$$
The final algebraic form $\sqrt{2RSB}$ in the $Q(\cdot)$ function may appear different unless we carefully track the relationship $T=1/R$ and distinguish between one-sided vs. two-sided bandwidth. Small discrepancies typically arise in these details—specifically how $A$, $T$, and $B$ are defined or normalized.
If we arrive at:
$$Q\!\left(\sqrt{\frac{A^2T}{4N_0}}\right)$$
but want:
$$Q\!\left(\sqrt{2RSB}\right)$$
the mismatch typically stems from either not correctly inserting the factor $\frac{R}{B}$ (i.e. $\frac{1}{TB}$) or from confusing the half-energy $\frac{A^2T}{4}$ with the full "peak amplitude" energy $A^2T$. When we consistently apply the relationships:
$$R = \frac{1}{T}, \quad E_b = \frac{A^2T}{4}, \quad RSB = \frac{E_b}{N_0}\frac{R}{B}$$
we obtain:
$$P_b = Q\!\left(\sqrt{\frac{2E_b}{N_0}}\right) = Q\!\left(\sqrt{2RSB}\right)$$
as expected for ASK with coherent detection.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

What does RSB stand for?

"RSB" is just a shorthand for $\frac{E_b}{N_0}\frac{R}{B}$, where $E_b$ is energy per bit, $N_0$ is noise spectral density, $R$ is bit rate, and $B$ is bandwidth. It groups these terms into one ratio for convenience.

Yes, I saw that, but why "RSB"? I've never come across that abbreviation (?).

I made it up. R is bit rate, S is the signal/noise term and B is bandwidth.

Ok, just wondering, because the OP used it as if everybody would know what it was ... Should have asked the OP, but since you also used it I thought it might be common.

@AlexRudimer So here we use to calculate the capacity with the baseband bandwidth Wich is of 3Khz and after using Ask we pass to $B=2* initial bandwidth$

@AlexRudimer I didn't get the same result, the error probability I got is $P_b = Q!\left(\sqrt{\frac{E_b}{N_0}}\right)$ without the factor 2 in the expression you gave
